# How much time should i spend with my puppy 4 month old?

Tags: socializing

How much time should I spent with my puppy. He is a border collie 4 month old. He seems to have a lot of energy and wants to socialize and play all the time. On one book, it says puppy needs socializing and interaction to build the bond with me. But on the other hand, I read that puppy should sleep/rest for 18-20 hours. For puppy with that age, that means he's going to be crated most of the time. I feel sad, especially when he whines inside the crate.

How much time does a puppy need for sleep/rest per day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puppies need a lot of sleep to aid in growth, average of 12-14 hours per day. Your pup being a border collie means Yes- a ton of energy. It is bred into your dogs DNA to run and to have a job (to be a working dog). You will find with some training and visits to the dog park, or daily dog walks will help with the pent up energy. Whining in the crate is normal, but being in for 18-20  hrs per day is not. Read up on his breed. This dog NEEDS something to do/ "needs a job".

On days you aren't working you should be spending a good 6-8 hours a day with your new addition, and on work days maybe wake up an hour earlier to designate time just for him, a walk, training time, fun in the sun, etc. When you come home from work fit him into your evening routine. Greet him when you come home, let him out of the crate and intead of just letting him potty extend those few minutes further into playtime, training time or another walk. I'd hate to say "YOU MUST SPEND 4 HOURS WITH HIM DOING NOTHING ELSE", you're human, it's not practical. Just try to integrate him into your family/daily lives as much as possible. Have fun with it and congrats on the new addition to the family.